# Xpath finding nodes that match two expressions

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm using xpath on the following xml, I need to extract only nodes that match
two expressions, maybe I'm doing it wrong because no nodes are returned.

```
<item>
    <title>a product</title>
    <link>http://www.aproduct.com</link>
    <description>cool product</description>
    <author>here@there.com</author>
    <id_product><![CDATA[ 6]]></id_product>
    <section><![CDATA[ industry]]></section>
</item>
<item>
    <title>another product</title>
    <link>http://www.anotherproduct.com</link>
    <description>awesome product</description>
    <author>here@there.com</author>
    <id_product><![CDATA[ 8]]></id_product>
    <section><![CDATA[ diy]]></section>
</item>
```

What I'm using now is

```
//item/section[text() = "industry"] | //item/id_product[ text() ="6"]
```

but I also tried

```
//item/section[ . = "industry"] | //item/id_product[ . ="8"]
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to select, the `item` element nodes or the `section` and `id_product` ones?

Comment: Also note that in your example there is no `section` whose content is equal to "industry" - there is one with content " industry" (with a leading space)

Comment: I'm trying to select all item elements with section child equal to "industry" AND id_product child equal to "6"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the text in the nodes you're trying to match starts with a space:

```
" industry"

" 8"
```

which is why `section[text() = "industry"]` doesn't select anything.

You could use

```
//item/section[normalize-space(.) = "industry"] | ...
```

**P.S.** Based on your later comment, it appears that what you want to select is quite different. You want to select the `item`, not its children, and you only want `item` elements for which *both* conditions hold true, not those for which *either* condition holds true. So:

```
//item[section[normalize-space(.) = "industry"] and 
       id_product[normalize-space(.) = "6"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried to use strip-space(.) but I got the following error:
    NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: The expression is not a legal expression.

any ideas?

Comment: Wait, now it works... without using strip-space(.).

I added that space like this:
    //item/section[ . = " industry"]

I know it is awful but it works :)

Comment: @Burn: my apologies about the `strip-space()`. I was thinking of `<xsl:strip-space>`, but as others have pointed out, the function for removing initial and trailing space (among other things) is `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fn:normalize-space(string)`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) xpath 1.0 function.

The Xpath would look like

```
//item/section[normalize-space(.) = "industry"] 
| 
//item/id_product[ normalize-space(.) ="6"]
```

**Update:** Based on the OP comment, i understand all the item nodes to be selected based on the values held by its child. So this expression will do

```
//item[normalize-space(section) = "industry" or normalize-space(id_product) ="6"]
```

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer. However I think the OP wants `and` in the predicate rather than `or` (if we can take his comment literally).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to select all item elements with section child equal to "industry" AND id_product child equal to "6"

Given that your example XML has leading spaces in the element values, you will need to use `normalize-space` when comparing:

```
//item[normalize-space(section) = "industry"][normalize-space(id_product) = "6"]
```

Multiple predicate expressions in sequence are effectively ANDed together, you can read the expression as

1. select all `item` elements in the document
2. filter this set of nodes to include only those that have a `section` child whose space-normalized value is `industry`
3. then filter *that* set to include only those that have an `id_product` child whose space-normalized value is `6`

Expressions like `//item/section[....]` would select the `section` element, not its parent `item`.